# different cell height in table view...iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

i am a new programmer of Iphone App..... i wants three cells in table **(which are different height)**

i write the code for this task..and output is satisfactory...... but i don't know.. this is right method or not.....

thanks in advance..... :)

```
CGRect frame=CGRectMake(5, 43, 311, 363);

UITableView *table=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];

table.dataSource=self;

table.delegate=self;



-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static int counter=1;

    if(counter==1)
    {
        counter=counter +1;
        return 163;

    }
    else if(counter ==2)
    {
        counter=counter +1;
        return 80;

    }
    else 
    {
        counter=counter +1;
        return 60;

    }
    if(counter==4)
    {
        counter=1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't right. Use `indexPath.row` instead of your `counter` variable. This will be the row number your delegate is being asked about. When scrolling upwards, for example, you may not get the expected results with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
static int counter=1;
```

Get the `row` from     NSIndexPath.

```
int row = indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 0):

your `static int counter` is not a global variable, so you code can't work.
It would work, if you make an ivar from it but that is not the correct way to solve that.
The `indexPath` variable provided by the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method holds the index of the actual item. Just call `indexPath.row` (this is the actual counter) in your code instead of your counter.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I guess you have a rotation of 3 rows heights, so the best way is to use `int row = indexPath.row % 3;` this will give you a cycling 0,1,2 as value to test instead of your counter

Comment: anyway there are better way to handle the whole "height problem", maybe using an array of float to store different values.